# How to retrieve nth highest details from below table using SQl?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Suppose if my table schema is like this item(item_id,item_name,item_price);
How i can retrieve   nth highest item_price  details ?
consider this table for above schema

```
ITEM_ID     ITEM_NAME       ITEM_PRICE
  101         pie             79
  102         chi             95
  100         dal             85
  103         tai             60
```

from that table i have to retrieve item_id,item_name of an item which has 2nd highest price.....

Comment: We need to see a query you have tried, in order to build on it. Or correct it.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the query you have tried so far.

Comment: Tag the dbms you are using. Add sample data and expected result. And also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear. We don't know if the rank column already in your table relates to marks or not. Assuming it doesn't you can do something like this in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
  StuRank.*
FROM 
  (SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY marks desc) AS rnk FROM student) StuRank
WHERE rnk = 2
```

There are a lot of unknowns though such as what you want to do if 2 students have the same marks.